# What are JavaScript Libraries?

Tags: javascript

I'm unclear on JavaScript libraries in general. Specifically, I was using WebStorm today and when I ran the program, the console said "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined." I used `prompt()` to get input. I'm confused because I thought `prompt()` was a built-in function. Does this have anything to do with libraries? And in any case, can anyone explain JavaScript's relationship with or dependence on them? The only other thing I've downloaded other than WebStorm was nodejs, and I'm not even sure I did that correctly.

Much obliged for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm confused because I thought prompt() was a built-in function. Does this have anything to do with libraries?

`prompt` is a member of the `window` object in browsers. If you attempt to call it in a non-browser environment, you'll get a Reference Error. So, no, it doesn't have anything to do with libraries in your case.

> And in any case, can anyone explain JavaScript's relationship with or dependence on them?

JavaScript has no dependence on libraries. However, some applications do. If you're writing a web application that uses AngularJS, for example, then your application depends on that library. It's just a bundle of code that someone else wrote that you can use.

Comment: Thank you to you both. So would I be right in saying that prompt() then is a method of the window object in the BOM? And if so, would the properties and methods of the window object be the only time you don't need to use dot notation? Sort of like when you import a function from a module in Python?

Comment: DOM (document object model). Yeah, props of the window object in the DOM. "And if so, would the properties and methods of the window object be the only time you don't need to use dot notation" Correct. I don't know Python, so I can't comment on that part.

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` function is a Property of the `window` object which is part of the browser.

I believe you are running the code in `node` where you don't have direct access t `window` object which is in-built property of the Browser.

Also, before calling the function/Property you can check if the property/function is defined or not like

```
if(functionName){
   functionName();
}
```

In javascript the ReferenceError represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Agalo.